# Cast to Kodi-solution

Tags: streaming, multimedia, kodi

I have a 16.04 box running Kodi (15.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1), and would like to have a cast to Kodi-option.

I'm aware that Kodi supports AirPlay, but support for this on Android phones, Windows and OpenSuSE clients is limited. The browser used on clients is Chrome / Chromium, and thus a Chromecast-like solution would be preferred.

I don't need *exactly* what Chromecast provides; installing additional plugins/software (on both clients and Kodi) is acceptable.

A solution that can stream movies stored on the remote device, and content like YouTube is preferred over a solution that only works with limited media types.

So is there any good way to cast content from Chrome / Chromium on Windows, Android and Linux, to Kodi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kodi supports **UPNP/DNLA** out-of-the-box (see [the wiki here](https://kodi.wiki/view/UPnP/Client))!

There is pretty decent support for this across platforms

- [UPNP/DNLA plugin for Chrome here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vget-extension-video-down/hniladkejehjfchadikcbjmgjaogciic?hl=en) and another one [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/deviceonline-upnpdlna-mc/ecedelmnmfbcnhomndfjadaeldibhdog?hl=en)
- [UPNP/DNLA on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/947793/can-windows-10-act-as-upnp-server)
- [UPNP/DNLA on OpenSUSE, Ubuntu, etc](https://en.opensuse.org/MiniDLNA)
- and there is an [abundance](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=dlna&c=apps&hl=en) of Apps [for Android](https://www.xda-developers.com/stream-your-media-to-any-upnpdlna-receiver-with-my-cloud-cast/)

Answer (score 1):

Oh yeah, I did exactly this! Well slightly different.

My Kodi was a recalbox https://recalbox.com

And my caster is Plex https://plex.tv (on my desktop)

Plex is fantastic, there is a free option, and it does a lot of cover parsing for your movies. I have plex server on my desktop. You browse to your server `localhost:32400` with chrome and you can edit your library there. Plex supports UPNP and a bunch of transcoding options.

Answer (score 1):

I've [made some small Java application (needs Java 1.8+) to play video content from laptop on Kodi](https://github.com/raydac/kodi-videoserver-app) and since 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT it can make some screencast (need FFmpeg installed)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an chrome plug-in called : [Play to Kodi](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/play-to-kodi/fncjhcjfnnooidlkijollckpakkebden?hl=en) for Youtube and more.

This should work on Windows and linux with chrome-browser

For Android there is an app called [Yatse: Kodi remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.leetzone.android.yatsewidgetfree&hl=en)

Check out this article for more information :

[How to Cast YouTube and Other Web Videos to Kodi (Like the Chromecast)](https://www.howtogeek.com/277116/how-to-cast-youtube-and-other-web-videos-to-kodi-like-the-chromecast/)