# Connect to wireless display in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, screencast

I was wondering if there's any progress in the WiDi compatibility for Ubuntu/Linux. In particular, I have a Microsoft Display Adapter that I can connect via HDMI to my monitor, and I would like to show my laptop screen on this external monitor via wireless.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Is this :
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DisplayCasting
what you mean - I assume you have googled.
I might have missed your specific point -apologies if I have. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I've seen it, but as far as I understand that works only with a few devices with Ubuntu Touch, not Ubuntu Desktop. And Ubuntu Touch has been discontinued, or am I missing something? I'd like to know if there's any way to get Display Casting to work on a PC with Ubuntu Desktop 20.04. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Miracast (or Wi-Fi Display) is the relevant technology here. Your Microsoft adapter acts as a Miracast sink, while Ubuntu should act as a Miracast source, so you can mirror your laptop display on your monitor screen wirelessly.

Progress is being made with [gnome-network-displays](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-network-displays) software, you can [install it via Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.NetworkDisplays).
You can test it on Ubuntu 20.04, but it surely would be better if you upgrade to the non-LTS Ubuntu 21.04 cause some problems have been solved since.

Comment: 21.04 is not out yet.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04, here is a detailed answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1280642/451019

Comment: Does the laptop in this case connect to the miracast dongle via Wifi-Direct or a common wifi network?