# How do I connect Ubuntu 20.04 to a Smart-TV?

Tags: display-manager, smart-tv

How do I connect my smart TV to Ubuntu (20.04 LTS) as secondary display, wirelessly. Can't find any option anywhere...

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [update your question with more details](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1310720/edit). Did you try a HDMI cable? Did you connect the cable to the computer? Did you connect the cable to the TV? Did you open the computer's Settings menu and go to the **Displays** section? If you don't edit your question and provide more details how can we help?

Comment: No, forget to mention I want to connect wireless, sorry ... Like adding the Smart-TV (Samsung) as secondary wireless display ... Just switched to Ubuntu from W10, just a click there, really missing that easy way on Ubuntu ;-)

Comment: There's a complete answer I've written on flatpak+gnome displays for samsung smart tv that could be a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/a/1280642

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try to gnome-network-displays, installable through means of Flatpak system.
Keep in mind that it's considered "experimental" by its authors, meaning it may not work at all for you.
Also I don't know how it will be on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, you'd better be on Ubuntu 21.04 (in beta as of my writing) cause it has several bugfixes and features relevant here.

Comment: 21.04 is not out yet.

Answer (score 0):

There's a complete answer I've written on flatpak+gnome displays for samsung smart tv that could be a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/a/1280642

Answer (score 0):

I watch movies on my Smart TV that are stored on my PC using the VLC Media Player.
You just need to open the movie on your PC using VLC, click on "Playback", then on "Renderer" and choose your Smart TV or any device that supports it.
You can even stream from your phone to the Smart TV that way.

Source: https://linuxhint.com/stream_linux_to_tv/

Answer (score -2):

Connect your pc or laptop to your smart-tv with wifi and then go to display in settings and then customize your settings such like which display will be your primary screen and other settings similar to Windows.

Comment: Ok - but how do I connect the smart-tv with the pc via network? Cant find an option to do so, sorry

Comment: Ok try these instructions https://linuxhint.com/stream_linux_to_tv/ @UrbanEgoCustom

Comment: "Smart TV" implies "not via hdmi" This answer isn't helpful and the comment link provided also isn't helpful as none of them actually address connecting to a smart tv.