# Error while trying to connect to my samsung tv with org.gnome.NetworkDisplays on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, desktop-recording, p2p

Following this [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1280642/269484) answer I tried to mirror my screen to my samsung TV, but it failed with an error.

Flow:

1. I installed the software using the guide
2. I ran the sotware
3. Saw my TV on the GUI
4. First time conecting I saw an option on my TV to allow or deny the connection and I chose 'Allow'
5. The GUI was showing this message for a while "Establishing connection to sink"
6. Afterwards there was the message : "Error"

Sys info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL 5.13.0-44-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 18:44:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

App output:

```
$ flatpak run org.gnome.NetworkDisplays
Gtk-Message: 23:48:55.996: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 23:48:55.997: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 23:48:56.062: Error calling DBus method during Screencast portal initialization: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.ScreenCast” on object at path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop

** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 23:48:56.062: Error initing screencast portal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.ScreenCast” on object at path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop

** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 23:48:56.062: Screencasting portal is unavailable! It is required to select the monitor to stream!

** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 23:48:56.062: Falling back to X11! You need to fix your setup to avoid issues (XDG Portals and/or mutter screencasting support)!
```

syslog:

```
Jun  7 23:48:55 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL systemd[2385]: Started flatpak-org.gnome.NetworkDisplays-15111.scope.
Jun  7 23:49:00 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: P2P-DEVICE-FOUND 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 p2p_dev_addr=66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 pri_dev_type=7-0050F204-1 name='[TV] Samsung 7 Series (50)' config_methods=0x188 dev_capab=0x21 group_capab=0x0 wfd_dev_info=0x01131c440036 vendor_elems=1 new=0



Jun  7 23:49:09 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: P2P-FIND-STOPPED 
Jun  7 23:49:09 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634949.7914] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'Wi-Fi P2P Peer 66:1C:B0:8A:61:D0' (a4dbf060-c781-4b7c-bf1d-f827308a5036)
Jun  7 23:49:09 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634949.7915] audit: op="connection-add-activate" uuid="a4dbf060-c781-4b7c-bf1d-f827308a5036" name="Wi-Fi P2P Peer 66:1C:B0:8A:61:D0" pid=15117 uid=1000 result="success"
Jun  7 23:49:09 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634949.7917] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun  7 23:49:09 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634949.7919] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun  7 23:49:09 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL systemd-udevd[15140]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
Jun  7 23:49:09 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL systemd-udevd[15140]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jun  7 23:49:09 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL systemd-udevd[15140]: Could not set AlternativeName= or apply AlternativeNamesPolicy= on p2p-wlo1-3: File exists
Jun  7 23:49:09 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL systemd-udevd[15140]: p2p-wlo1-3: Could not apply link config, ignoring: File exists
Jun  7 23:49:10 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: P2P-GO-NEG-SUCCESS role=client freq=2412 ht40=0 peer_dev=66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 peer_iface=66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 wps_method=PBC
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: WPS-PBC-ACTIVE 
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: SME: Trying to authenticate with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (SSID='DIRECT-iW[TV] Samsung 7 Series (' freq=2412 MHz)
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.009687] p2p-wlo1-3: authenticate with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.009704] p2p-wlo1-3: No basic rates, using min rate instead
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.012276] p2p-wlo1-3: send auth to 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (try 1/3)
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-51 noise=9999 txrate=144400
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: Trying to associate with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (SSID='DIRECT-iW[TV] Samsung 7 Series (' freq=2412 MHz)
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.020037] p2p-wlo1-3: authenticated
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.020834] p2p-wlo1-3: associate with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (try 1/3)
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: Associated with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.022133] p2p-wlo1-3: RX AssocResp from 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.024023] p2p-wlo1-3: associated
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=14122 method=1
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 14122 method 1 (WSC) selected
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: WPS-CRED-RECEIVED 
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: WPS-SUCCESS 
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: P2P-GROUP-FORMATION-SUCCESS 
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.110713] p2p-wlo1-3: deauthenticating from 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL ModemManager[1299]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3': not supported by any plugin
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: SME: Trying to authenticate with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (SSID='DIRECT-iW[TV] Samsung 7 Series (' freq=2412 MHz)
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.525012] p2p-wlo1-3: authenticate with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.525031] p2p-wlo1-3: No basic rates, using min rate instead
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.527909] p2p-wlo1-3: send auth to 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (try 1/3)
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: Trying to associate with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (SSID='DIRECT-iW[TV] Samsung 7 Series (' freq=2412 MHz)
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.533939] p2p-wlo1-3: authenticated
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.536857] p2p-wlo1-3: associate with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (try 1/3)
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.538181] p2p-wlo1-3: RX AssocResp from 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.540736] p2p-wlo1-3: associated
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: Associated with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-50 noise=9999 txrate=144400
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: P2P-GROUP-STARTED p2p-wlo1-3 client ssid="DIRECT-iW[TV] Samsung 7 Series (" freq=2412 go_dev_addr=66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: dbus: Register group object '/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/8/Groups/iW'
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.617361] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): p2p-wlo1-3: link becomes ready
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634952.7016] sup-iface[0x564588422a10,(null)]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <warn>  [1654634952.7017] sup-iface[0x564588422a10,(null)]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634952.7048] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): P2P Group supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634952.7056] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634952.7064] dhcp4 (p2p-wlo1-3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL avahi-daemon[1193]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface p2p-wlo1-3.IPv6 with address fe80::aca0:21ae:ef27:9f5e.
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL avahi-daemon[1193]: New relevant interface p2p-wlo1-3.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL avahi-daemon[1193]: Registering new address record for fe80::aca0:21ae:ef27:9f5e on p2p-wlo1-3.*.
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <warn>  [1654634952.8056] dhcp4 (p2p-wlo1-3): could not get netmask from lease
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634952.8057] dhcp4 (p2p-wlo1-3): state changed unknown -> fail
Jun  7 23:49:18 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL systemd[2385]: Started VTE child process 15201 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 5051.
Jun  7 23:49:44 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634984.8714] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun  7 23:49:44 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <warn>  [1654634984.8731] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'Wi-Fi P2P Peer 66:1C:B0:8A:61:D0'
Jun  7 23:49:44 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634984.8742] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun  7 23:49:44 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL avahi-daemon[1193]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::aca0:21ae:ef27:9f5e on p2p-wlo1-3.
Jun  7 23:49:44 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL avahi-daemon[1193]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface p2p-wlo1-3.IPv6 with address fe80::aca0:21ae:ef27:9f5e.
Jun  7 23:49:44 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL avahi-daemon[1193]: Interface p2p-wlo1-3.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jun  7 23:49:44 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634984.9034] dhcp4 (p2p-wlo1-3): canceled DHCP transaction
Jun  7 23:49:44 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634984.9035] dhcp4 (p2p-wlo1-3): state changed fail -> done
Jun  7 23:49:44 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7251.827399] p2p-wlo1-3: deauthenticating from 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jun  7 23:49:44 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <warn>  [1654634984.9123] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
Jun  7 23:49:45 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: p2p-wlo1-3: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Jun  7 23:49:45 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: P2P-GROUP-REMOVED p2p-wlo1-3 client reason=REQUESTED
Jun  7 23:49:45 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <warn>  [1654634985.0323] sup-iface[0x564588422a10,p2p-wlo1-3]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Jun  7 23:49:45 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-wlo1-3 disabled_11b_rates=0
Jun  7 23:49:45 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL NetworkManager[1202]: <info>  [1654634985.1098] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): P2P Group supplicant interface state: ready -> down
Jun  7 23:50:18 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: P2P-DEVICE-LOST p2p_dev_addr=66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0
Jun  7 23:50:18 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL wpa_supplicant[1241]: dbus: Unregister peer object '/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/4/Peers/661cb08a61d0'
```

kern.log:

```
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.009687] p2p-wlo1-3: authenticate with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.009704] p2p-wlo1-3: No basic rates, using min rate instead
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.012276] p2p-wlo1-3: send auth to 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (try 1/3)
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.020037] p2p-wlo1-3: authenticated
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.020834] p2p-wlo1-3: associate with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (try 1/3)
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.022133] p2p-wlo1-3: RX AssocResp from 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.024023] p2p-wlo1-3: associated
Jun  7 23:49:11 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7218.110713] p2p-wlo1-3: deauthenticating from 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.525012] p2p-wlo1-3: authenticate with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.525031] p2p-wlo1-3: No basic rates, using min rate instead
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.527909] p2p-wlo1-3: send auth to 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (try 1/3)
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.533939] p2p-wlo1-3: authenticated
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.536857] p2p-wlo1-3: associate with 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (try 1/3)
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.538181] p2p-wlo1-3: RX AssocResp from 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.540736] p2p-wlo1-3: associated
Jun  7 23:49:12 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7219.617361] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): p2p-wlo1-3: link becomes ready
Jun  7 23:49:44 ofirm-ZenBook-UX435EGL-UX435EGL kernel: [ 7251.827399] p2p-wlo1-3: deauthenticating from 66:1c:b0:8a:61:d0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

Comment: Related issue: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-network-displays/-/issues/221

Answer (score 1):

I've written [the answer you mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017249/samsung-tv-mirror-screen/1280642#1280642) some years ago, and have not used this feature for a while. I decided to try that again, on the same TV, but now on another computer. And it didn't work directly, then after a few tries it worked again. Note that I'm only a user, I don't know details of [gnome-network-displays](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-network-displays) project, which is complex. I will try to help you somehow, by sharing some more details of my system.

First of all, this is how my console looks like when it works correctly:

```
$ flatpak run org.gnome.NetworkDisplays
Gtk-Message: 20:16:17.837: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 20:16:17.930: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 20:16:17.932: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 20:16:29.836: WfdClient: No resolution found, falling back to standard FullHD resolution.
```

So, I strongly believe this is the really bad part on your system:

```
** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 23:48:56.062: Error calling DBus method during Screencast portal initialization: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.ScreenCast” on object at path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop

** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 23:48:56.062: Error initing screencast portal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.ScreenCast” on object at path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop

** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 23:48:56.062: Screencasting portal is unavailable! It is required to select the monitor to stream!

** (gnome-network-displays:2): WARNING **: 23:48:56.062: Falling back to X11! You need to fix your setup to avoid issues (XDG Portals and/or mutter screencasting support)!
```

By the way, which system are you using? Mine is Ubuntu 22.04.

Searching for issues regarding `GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.ScreenCast”`, I found this [gnome-shell issue on PopOS](https://github.com/pop-os/gnome-shell/issues/20). But you seem to be using Ubuntu 20.04 on kernel 5.13... even more upgraded than mine. Mine is kernel 5.11.

```
$ uname -a
Linux imcoelho-Nitro-AN515-43 5.11.0-49-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 12 17:36:34 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.38.4

$ dpkg -l |grep xserver-xorg-core 
ii  xserver-xorg-core                             2:1.20.11-1ubuntu1.2                                                 amd64        Xorg X server - core server
```

Another important component to check is `wpasupplicant`... on my Ubuntu 22.04 system, its version is `(2:2.9.0-21)`.

I had some issues here, decided to install PipeWire for audio as they [seem to recommend here](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.NetworkDisplays) (but I don't recommend that), then after a reboot, it worked again for me. But I don't know what fixed it for me, if it was really some audio stuff, or just some random reboot.

**My final suggestion** is that you try Ubuntu 22.04 on Live USB mode, then validate if that works for your hardware... if that's working, then you can try to debug your actual system. Hope this helps.